# How to delete file in dropzone?

Tags: angularjs, dropzone.js

```
      init: function() {
            dzClosure = this;

            document.getElementById("place-order").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
                dzClosure.processQueue();
            });

            this.on("sendingmultiple", function(data, xhr, formData) {
                formData.append("key", $scope.formData.order_id);
            });

            this.on('success', function(file, resp) {
                console.log(resp); //result - {error:false, file_id:10}
                file_ids.push(resp.file_id);
            });
        },
        removedfile: function(file) {
            console.log(file_ids);
            x = confirm('Do you want to delete?');
            if (!x) return false;
            var name = file.name;
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'orders/fileDelete.php',
                data: {"file_id": file_ids},
                dataType: 'json'
            });
            var _ref;
            return (_ref = file.previewElement) != null ? _ref.parentNode.removeChild(file.previewElement) : void 0;
        }
```

Above my code working fine. But I want to delete my mysql row while clicking on the "Remove" button in dropzone. I am unable to get the current `file_id` in my `removedfile` function. Please help me and let me know how I will get `resp.file_id` in my `removedfile` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lots of research I found where was error in my code.

Actually my ajax responded JSON. But here is dropzone.js not getting json data. So I have converted my dynamic String data to JSON format.

Code:

```
this.on('success', function(file, resp) {
    console.log(resp); // result - {error:false, file_id:10}
    var response = JSON.parse(resp);
    file.file_id = response.file_id;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could set an id property to file on success event, then on removal just get it as file.id. Hope this helps you.

```
init: function() {
        dzClosure = this;

        document.getElementById("place-order").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            dzClosure.processQueue();
        });

        this.on("sendingmultiple", function(data, xhr, formData) {
            formData.append("key", $scope.formData.order_id);
        });

        this.on('success', function(file, resp) {
            file.id = resp.file_id;
        });
    },
    removedfile: function(file) {
        x = confirm('Do you want to delete?');
        if (!x) return false;
        //send delete to backend only if file was uploaded.
        //Dropzone will cancel requests in progress itself.
        if(file.id) {
            $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'orders/fileDelete.php',
            data: {"file_id": file.id},
            dataType: 'json'
        });
        }
    }
```

Comment: I findout my error. I have returned simple string. So my `file_id` was not working properly. Here I have changed in my code `var response = JSON.parse(resp);
                    file.file_id = response.file_id;`   Thank you for your try.